# Get unique values from 2 columns and match these unique values in another sheet to populate the cell with the word OK

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help to correct my code to check the unique values in **2 columns G and AI** if is not empty or **column G and AJ** from a *sheet named start* and then look for these unique value match on ***column A** in a sheet named Final*. When It finds these value in **column A** It needs to populate the **column C** in the same row as the match number is located with the **word OK.**

Always will be 2 columns to be checked for a unique value.
The values of *Column 8 + the values of column 36* on the **sheet Start** need to be checked for unique values. However, if Columns 8 and 36 are empty then the code needs to check *column 7 + column 35*.
[image]

I am using this code but seems incomplete.

```
 Sheets("Start").Activate
    Sintrlastrow1 = Sheets("Start").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    SLastColumn = Sheets("Start").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
         Dim idsConsumerGalactic As Object
        Dim StartSheet As Range
        Dim Count As Integer
        Set StartSheet = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Sintrlastrow1, SLastColumn))
        Set idsConsumerGalactic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
      For Count = 2 To Sintrlastrow1
        If Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 8).Value <> "" And Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 36).Value <> "" Then '' --->>> columns that need to be checked for unique value 
            valor = Sheets("Interdiction").Cells(Count, 8).Value And Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 36).Value  ''--->>> If columns H and AI is <> ""
        Else
            valor = Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 7).Value And Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 35).Value ''--->>> if columns H and AI is "" then needed to check conlumns G and AJ for unique values
        End If
        
            If idsConsumerGalactic.Exists(valor) Then
                idsConsumerGalactic(valor) = (idsConsumerGalactic(valor) + 1)
            Else
                idsConsumerGalactic.Add valor, 1
            End If
        Next Count
    
    Sheets("Final").Activate
        For Each consumer In idsConsumerGalactic  ''-->> Trying to loop the Final sheet to find the unique value match where is the row of the unique value and add OK on the column C  
            If (idsConsumerGalactic(consumer) = 1) Then
                Set Match = Sheets("Final").Cells.Find(What:=consumer, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Match Then
             Sheets("Final").Cells(consumer.Row, 3).Value = "OK"
            End If
           End If
             Next
```

How to check both 2 columns for unique values and then look for it in another sheet??

How to populate the cell on **column C** with the word **OK** when the code finds the unique value from **columns G and AI** *from sheet Start* on **column A** in the *sheet Final* ?

[image: Result I need]

in the image the consumer numbers 2,4 and 5 are unique from column G and AI.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I need help to correct my code to check the unique values in 2 columns G and AI from a sheet named start and then look for these unique values on column A on a sheet named Final. When It finds this value in column A It needs to populate the column C in the same row as the match number with the word OK.

Comment: Your code is confusing - for example your description mentions two sheets but your code has 3.  Also unclear what's the purpose of the first `If` block in the `Count` loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams so it makes sense why is not working. 
well. in this case Yes, it is only 2 sheets named Start (where is the  2 columns that I need to get the unique data) and the sheet named Final where need to populate the column C if the word OK when the unique matchs

Comment: It would help a lot if you edit your question to clean up the code and resolve the sheet names...

Comment: the first `IF` is to get the 2 columns to look for unique (because if the `column  H and AI is  = ""` then the column to be checked for unique will be `columns G and AJ`.

Comment: the block `Count` I am trying to get the correct row where the unique value is located on `column A sheet Final` so the column C will be populated.

Comment: @TimWilliams I changed the question, does it make sense now?

Comment: What about this: `valor = Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 7).Value And Sheets("Start").Cells(Count, 35).Value` - the `And` here is difficult to figure out, so what is the value you're wanting in `valor` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams are the columns to be checked for unique values. (I am trying to store it in the dictionary). the data in these 2 columns are the client number, however, sometimes the columns 8 + 36 may be empty and the code need to get check other 2  columns  7 + 35 columns for the unique values.

Comment: The unique values need to be unique in both columns ex:
if on column H the is number 2,3,4,5,  but on column AI there are the numbers 2,4,5, only number 3 is unique

Comment: But you're combining those 2 values with `And` - that will return a value if both numbers are the same, but zero if they're not - is that what you intend? That will raise an error if you have string inputs like the values in ColG

Comment: I need to check all the values on both columns and find the unique value on Final sheet. However, I don't want to comper the values from column H with the values of the column AJ. I want to check all the values, in this case, I have 520 rows it is a total of 1040 values to be checked for a unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess:

```vb
Sub tester()

    Dim wsStart As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, wsFinal As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, rw As Range, v, v2, k, m
    
    Set wsStart = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Start") ' or ThisWorkbook.sheets("Start") ?
    Set wsFinal = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Final")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lastRow = wsStart.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rw In wsStart.Range("A2:AJ" & lastRow).Rows
        v = rw.Cells(8).Value
        v2 = rw.Cells(36).Value
        
        If Len(v) = 0 Or Len(v2) = 0 Then
            v = rw.Cells(7).Value
            v2 = rw.Cells(35).Value
        End If
        
        dict(v) = dict(v) + 1
        dict(v2) = dict(v2) + 1
    Next rw
    
    For Each k In dict
        If dict(k) = 1 Then
            m = Application.Match(k, wsFinal.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then wsFinal.Cells(m, 3).Value = "OK"
        End If
    Next k
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. It is working really well and it is what I need.

Comment: A quick question. Is there a way for the works **OK** already appear as bold?

Comment: Yes you can set the cell's Font Bold property to True